# How can I "tag" or make documents in a library easily searchable in MOSS 2007?

Tags: search, document-library, document, tagging

I have a document library (MOSS 2007) that I want to try to make more easily searchable. Is there a way to "tag" the documents or something, so when I search for, say, "report", I will get all the documents that have to do with reports?

Answer (score 1):

you can look at the following it will help you out to understand how the search function works with crawling!

Use crawl rules to determine what content gets crawled (Office SharePoint Server 2007)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262071(v=office.12)

Limit or increase the quantity of content that is crawled

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262531(v=office.12)

good place to start:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544688/document-library-crawl

SharePoint 2007 - Creating custom search scopes

http://dattard.blogspot.co.uk/2007/04/sharepoint-2007-creating-custom-search.html

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to achieve this is to use search scopes. A good article on this:
http://blogen.siderys.com/2009/02/creating-scopes-for-search-in.html

Further research on this should show you how to narrow results to a specified document library.

Answer (score -1):

Go to link, you have a idea to create Meta Tags and quick to get Related Documents.

http://www.endusersharepoint.com/EUSP2010/2010/06/01/understanding-managed-metadata-in-sharepoint-2010-its-impact-on-taxonomy-navigation-and-search-part-1-focusing-on-managed-metadata-term-store-navigation-and-search/

Comment: This is a 2007 question.

Comment: I have edited the original question to make it more clear that this refers to the 2007 version of SharePoint.